# How to prevent wiggles in Razor view for custom Html helpers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I created a custom Html helper and it works as expected.
However, Visual Studio displays wiggles in the Razor view:

[image]

How could I get rid of the wiggles?

EDIT: added method implementation below

[image]

Comment: What error does VS display and please add how you implemented the helper method.